# Как программно вызвать зависание компьютера?

Tags: c#

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заставить компьютер зависнуть? =) Чем бы его нагрузить так сильно на C#?

Заранее благодарен!

**Дополнено.**

```
public static void f1()
{
    double x = 0;
    double z = 0;
    double y = 0;
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    while (true)
    {
        x *= Math.Pow(999999999999999999, 999999999999999);
        y *= Math.Pow(9999999999999999, x*1000000000);
        z *= Math.Pow(Math.Log10(Math.Sin(x*999999)), y*999999*1000000000);

        ms.Read(BitConverter.GetBytes(z), 1, 1);

    }
}
```

Делал так в 8 потоков... нифига. О_о

Comment: Значит арифметики мало, нужно что-то более тяжёлое. Хотя бы плавающую точку добавить. Или какие-нибудь сложные структуры данных, с простыми типами наверно любой язык справляется на рас.

Comment: Просто из любопытства, а зачем вам это? )

Comment: Когда я этим страдал, мне тупо было скучно на работе, и стрельнуло в голову выяснить на сколько мощный язык, только потом вычитал что мой алгоритм тупо бесполезен, всё было предусмотрено разработчиками, дальше было лень фигнёй маяться.

Comment: Один из пунктов ТЗ... ничего не поделаешь =)))

Comment: Уточните:

Это винда?

Требуется сие сотворить именно на C# или можно использовать C ?

Привилегии пользователя ?

Требуется отдать процессорное время одному процессу или можно 
загрузить комп прерываниями от харда, так чтоб мышь не шевелилась ?

Answer (score 2):

Для подвешивания компьютера надо ввести OS в тяжелый paging с откачиванием страниц на диск.
При этом paging надо вызвать у достаточного (сравнимым с количеством ядер) числа процессов.
Параллельно для полноты ощущений можно повесить по парочке процессов с бесконечным циклом на ядро.

Мой маленький эксперимент в течении нескольких минут привел туповатое творение Билла Гейтса (Windows-XP на Compaq Pentium(R)DualCore 2GB RAM) в полный ступор, окончательно оживить удалось только вытащив шнур питания (!) т.к. на кнопку выключения комп уже не реагировал.

Касперский же при первом запуске бинарника распознал в нем вредоносный soft и чего-то написал про Generic, но я быстро перевел прогу в разряд доверенных и название Generic-a упустил.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <errno.h>

#ifdef WIN32
#include  <windows.h>
#else
#define Sleep(x) sleep((x+500)/1000)
#endif

#define MEMSIZE 1000000000  // миллиард
#define CPU   4
#define LIM   3

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int  i;
  char str[1024];

  if (ac > LIM) {
    printf ("Exit\n");
    Sleep(5000);
    exit(1);
  }
  if (ac == 2 && av[1][0] == '+') {
    printf ("Run CPU\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    while(1)
      i++;
  }

  if (ac == 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < CPU; i++) {
      sprintf(str,"start %s +",av[0]);
      system(str);
    }
  }

  sprintf (str,"start %s ",av[0]);
  for (i = 0; i < ac; i++)
    strcat(str," x ");
  printf ("str = [%s]\n",str);
  system (str);
  char *mem = malloc(MEMSIZE);
  if (mem) {
    for (i = 0; i < MEMSIZE; i++)
      mem[i] = i*i;
    printf ("memory 1\n"); fflush(stdout);
    Sleep(2000);
    int l;
    for (i = 0; i < MEMSIZE; i++) {
      l = ((rand()*MEMSIZE))%MEMSIZE;  // здесь не стал бороться с отрицательными
      if (l < 0) {
        l = -l;
        if (l >= MEMSIZE) {  // на всякий случай 
                             // (реально не было, как и следовало ожидать)
          printf ("l = %d\n",l); fflush(stdout);
          l = MEMSIZE-1;
        }
      }
      mem[i] = mem[l]+i;
    }

    printf ("memory 2\n");  fflush(stdout);
  }
  Sleep(2000);

  printf ("End\n");
}
```

Желающие могут поиграться с параметрами и добавлением бесконечных циклов.

Делал на gcc из MinGW.

ХэшКод !  Все таки надо что-то сделать для удобного ввода текста программ по Copy/Paste (проблема с табуляциями в выравниваемом тексте программы).

Comment: Do: QueueUserAPC(0, -2, 0) :Loop

Ждём несколько секунд =)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вычисление факториала, на FAR + C++, комп зависал огого. )
Ну или сделайте так, чтобы было типа такого

```
while(1){
    //какие-то громоздкие вычисление
}
```

После этого сделайте так, чтобы данный процесс стал "высоко приоритетным или в режиме реального времени".

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание, если процессор многоядерный (сейчас почти все такие) - то вам нужно в обязательном порядке делать как минимум несколько потоков, а то и дочерних процессов, минимум по одному на ядро, лучше - по два (всякие там гипертрединги...)

Можно проще, по одному потоку/процессу на ядро с выставлением приоритета реального времени потокам/процессам.

В C++ приоритет можно изменить вот так:

`SetThreadPriority ( GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);`

Все вышеперечисленное 100% применимо к C++.

При написании кода на C# для платформы .NET вы можете столкнуться с тем, что интерпретатор нет будет каким-то образом влиять на состояние системы... К сожалению, в таких вещах не копался...

Answer (score 1):

NtSuspendProcess(Csrss) - RIT останавливается и всё глухо виснет(только ввод, что под зависанием понимает ТС не известно).
Можно исчерпать память ядра. Например цикл доставки APC в тред, без её вызова исчерпает память, что приведёт к зависаниям, глюкам и лагам. Вредоносно.

Answer (score 0):

Хм, прочитайте в документации C#, как он работает с распределением памяти, возможно такое, что вы не сможете нагрузить так, чтобы прям ПК завис. Максимум полностью заполните ОЗУ и то, думаю, у него есть инструменты, лечащие данную уязвимость.

Сам пытался простеньким возведением в степень забить полностью ОЗУ ПК, но не на С#. В итоге после 8 часов (на работе), ПК работал, как и работает, но прога досчитала до такого гигантского числа, что возведение в квадрат занимало несколько часов и финальная цифра состояла из десятков тысяч знаков. Он число раскладывал и как-то по частям совершал арифметику.

ИМХО если уж и хотите забить, то делайте ударение на проц, пробуйте несколько потоков.
Могу сильно ошибаться, так как с С# не сталкивался, просто попытался пример привести на своём опыте.

**Как обещал, мой код бесконечного цикла**

```
def x():
    y = 2
    while y > 1:
    y = y ** 2
    print y
    n = len(str(y))
    print n

x()
```

Answer (score 0):

Хм, максимальный приоритет процессу + бесконечный цикл. Да хотя бы и while(true);

На плюсах такое, как я думаю, должно заморозить компьютер намертво. Может, и на шарпе тоже=)

Надеюсь, это не во вредоносных целях задано =D

Comment: Нужен не просто максимальный.. надо выбрать приоритет REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS и THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL для треда. Тогда даже ядерные функции не будут ваш цикл прерывать

Comment: Вот я про это речь и веду =) Чтоб всё процессорное время доставалось только этому процессу и никому более.